# Why can't I populate my array with the URL from the user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I want to populate the array with URLs but also display those URLs one by one.  For example, one user comes on, uploads a file, it gets stored in the array and displayed.  The next user comes on, uploads a file, it gets stored in the array and displayed, etc.

Essentially, I just want to be able to create `<img/>` tags dynamically in the `<Feed/>` component for users to come online and upload files followed by getting placed into the array.

What am I doing wrong?

Inside Main components

```
this.state = {
   pictures: [],
   previewImgURL: ''
};

displayImage() {
    let pictures = this.state.pictures;
    let previewImgURL = this.state.previewImgURL;
    this.setState({pictures: [...previewImgURL, previewImgURL]});
    console.log(pictures);
    return <Feed src={pictures}/>;
};

render() {
   return(
      <div className="uploaded-pics">
        {this.displayImage()}
      </div>
   );
}
```

Inside Feed component

```
import React from 'react';
import './Feed.scss';

const feed = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="parent">
            <img src={props.src} className="img-fluid" alt=""/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default feed;
```

Comment: You will need persistent data storage to have this work between different users. React state is confined to a browser session. Once you close the tab or browser, the state is destroyed. So different users in different places cannot add image URLs to the same state. So you have to make data persist by using a database for example.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the preview image? does `picture` also has the actual image (not preview)?

Comment: @sawyerrken you know, I actually thought the same thing a couple of minutes ago.  In other words, I would just need to keep my `<Feed/>` component as is because different users who are logging in and uploading files would show regardless of what I'm trying to achieve now.  Is this what you mean?  I only ask because I was see if what you & I are thinking is consistent.

Comment: @JosephD I want to store it in the array (the URL) as well as display it.

Comment: @luvs2spuge so `pictures` is just an array of image urls (i.e strings)?

Comment: @JosephD. yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this code helps. I have used react hooks to simplify things, I have also use some ES6 stuff like fat arrow functions. And instead of an image upload I have used a simple input text with an "add" button (just for simulation)

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-microservice-2nev1

And here I am assuming this is for a single user. As I said in my comments, if you would want this to work across different users then you will have to use something like a database to store the links to the database and a method to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, going to give this a shot!

Answer (score 0):

At least the Feed should iterate over the `pictures` array

```
import React from 'react';
import './Feed.scss';

const feed = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="parent">
            {props.src.map(item => 
                <img src={item} className="img-fluid" alt=""/>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default feed;
```

This line

`this.setState({pictures: [...previewImgURL, previewImgURL]});`

probably should look like this

`this.setState({pictures: [...pictures, previewImgURL]});`

Comment: just tried this, it doesn't work.  I believe something's wrong with my `displayImage()` function